# MPMoviePlayerController not working properly in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have the  following code that works just fine on my test phone with iOS 4.3. But when I test it on another phone with iOS 5.1 it doesn't seem to work. Can you help me?

```
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:
                                           [NSURL URLWithString: [defaults objectForKey:@"videoPath"]]];

        player.view.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 320, 198);

        self.thePlayer = player;

        [player release];

        [self.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.thePlayer.view];

        [self.thePlayer play];
```

Comment: Is it crashed, or not shown, or what? What the problem?

Comment: It isn't shown. It does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

Declare **MPMoviePlayerController *player** in **.h** file. It will work.

Thanks